# Adding entry inside a table in database

Tags: mysql

I wanted to add an entry inside a table in SQL database.

For example I have the following Database

```
CREATE TABLE `distributor_geneology` (
  `distributor_gen_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sponsor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `rank` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
);
```

And I want to add an entry in `sponsor_id` or say `id` inside a database.

First, I imported the database in my SQL Workbench then In my SQL Workbench, I ran a command  `select * from distributor_geneology` which gave me

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'dba_db.distributor_genelogy' doesn't exist
```

[Question] How can I create/add Entry for ID (or sponsor ID or any other filed)?

Comment: Spelling mistake? It is `geneology` not `genelogy`?

Answer (score 1):

One typical way which data would enter a MySQL database is via an `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO distributor_geneology (distributor_gen_id, user_id, id, sponsor_id, rank)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
```

I am inserting `1` everywhere, but you may alter the tuple with the values you want.

Another way to get data into a table is bulk loading via `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: I am getting the following error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank) VALUES     (11112, 11112, 11112, 11112, "FC")' at line 1` when following your code. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Your definition for the `distributor_geneology` table does not show any varchar (text) columns.  So I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Tim can you please explain your comment in answer? or in another comment?

Comment: TIm I mean what do you mean when you said `Your definition for the distributor_geneology table does not show any varchar (text) columns. So I don't know what you are trying to do`

Comment: You defined your table to accept only integers, but you are trying to insert a string.

Comment: if i change that string into an integer something like this 'VALUES
(11112, 1111, 11112, 11112, 112);' Still the same error :/

Answer (score 1):

**For your first part of your question which is "Add an entry to inside table"**

this operation called **insertion** in the database and the keyword database used to insert data is `insert into`

It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two ways:

**1-** specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

you can rearrange the columns orders as you want but must the values be the same order of the columns and you can let any column null if you don't want to insert any data in this column  **but be careful if you have** `not null` **column you must insert in you query**
in your case, all the columns you have are `not null`.

2- if you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query. make sure the order of the values is in the same order as the columns in the table

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

**For your second part of your question which is "Error Code: 1146. Table 'dba_db.distributor_genelogy' doesn't exist"**

First, ensure you imported the DB correctly and if yes > write try to use DB name in your query.

```
select * from DB_Name.Table_Name
```

**Edit:** 
Try this query format

```
INSERT INTO distributor_geneology (distributor_gen_id, user_id, id, sponsor_id, rank)
VALUES
    (10, '10', 10, 10, 10);
```

please note I put second value between 2 quotes because you are defining the user_id as **varchar** which means not an integer so we should put it between qouts

Comment: Your second column-less insert should probably be avoided, at least in production.